# Error check within do block in Haskell

Tags: haskell

i have the following set of actions:

```
action1 :: IO Bool
action2 :: IO Bool
action3 :: IO Bool
```

some actions are just composition of another actions

```
complexAction = do
  action1
  action2
  action3
```

What i need is the construction that checks result of each action and returns False in a case of false. I can do it manually but i know for sure that haskell does have tools to get rid of that kind of boilerplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use `MaybeT` monad transformer instead. Using it has many advantages over just returning `IO Bool`:

- Your actions can have different types and return values (not just true/false). If you don't need any results, just use `MaybeT IO ()`.
- Later ones can depend on results of preceding ones.
- Since `MaybeT` produces monads that are instances of `MonadPlus`, you can use all monad plus operations. Namely `mzero` for a failed action and `x mplus y`, which will run `y` iff `x` fails.

A slight disadvantage is that you have to `lift` all `IO` actions to `MaybeT IO`. This can be solved by writing your actions as `MonadIO m => ... -> m a` instead of `... -> IO a`.

For example:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

-- Lift print and putStrLn
print' :: (MonadIO m, Show a) => a -> m ()
print' = liftIO . print

putStrLn' :: (MonadIO m) => String -> m ()
putStrLn' = liftIO . putStrLn

-- Add something to an argument
plus1, plus3 :: Int -> MaybeT IO Int
plus1 n    = print' "+1"   >> return (n + 1)
plus3 n    = print' "+3"   >> return (n + 3)

-- Ignore an argument and fail
justFail :: Int -> MaybeT IO a
justFail _ = mzero

-- This action just succeeds with () or fails.
complexAction :: MaybeT IO ()
complexAction = do
  i <- plus1 0
  justFail i -- or comment this line out <----------------<
  j <- plus3 i
  print' j

-- You could use this to convert your actions to MaybeT IO:
boolIOToMaybeT :: IO Bool -> MaybeT IO ()
boolIOToMaybeT x = do
  r <- lift x
  if r then return () else mzero
-- Or you could have even more general version that works with other
-- transformers as well:
boolIOToMaybeT' :: (MonadIO m, MonadPlus m) => IO Bool -> m ()
boolIOToMaybeT' x = do
  r <- liftIO x
  if r then return () else mzero

main :: IO ()
main = runMaybeT complexAction >>= print'
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is

```
complexAction = fmap and (sequence [action1, action2, action3])
```

But you could also write your own combinator to stop after the first action:

```
(>>/) :: Monad m => m Bool -> m Bool -> m Bool
a >>/ b = do
   yes  <- a
   if yes then b else return False
```

You'd want to declare the fixity to make it associative

```
infixl 1 >>/
```

Then you can do

```
complexAction = action1 >>/ action2 >>/ action3
```

Comment: The first way makes me a bit nervous because it relies on evaluation order, which means it relies on the implementation details of, say, `and`.

Comment: @RobinGreen No, it doesn't - `sequence` runs all the monadic actions in sequence then `and`s the result. You can't mess with evaluation order of `IO` actions by applying a pure function; it's impossible.

Comment: true, all the actions get run, but the thunks don't necessarily all get run. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

As Petr says, for anything but a narrow and contained case, you're almost certainly better off wiring your code for proper error handling from the outset. I know I've often regretted not doing this, condemning myself to some very tedious refactoring.

If I may, I'd like to recommend Gabriel Gonzalez's `errors` package, which imposes a little more coherence on Haskell's various error-handling mechanisms than has been traditional. It allows you to plumb `Either`s through your code, and `Either` is a good type for capturing errors. (By contrast, `Maybe` will lose information on the error side.) Once you've installed the package, you can write things like this:

```
module Errors where

import Control.Error
import Data.Traversable (traverse)

data OK = OK Int deriving (Show)

action1, action2, action3 :: IO (Either String OK)
action1 = putStrLn "Running action 1" >> return (Right $ OK 1)
action2 = putStrLn "Running action 2" >> return (Right $ OK 2)
action3 = putStrLn "Running action 3" >> return (Left "Oops on 3")

runStoppingAtFirstError :: [IO (Either String OK)] -> IO (Either String [OK])
runStoppingAtFirstError = runEitherT . traverse EitherT
```

...with output like

```
*Errors> runStoppingAtFirstError [action1, action2]
Running action 1
Running action 2
Right [OK 1,OK 2]
*Errors> runStoppingAtFirstError [action1, action3, action2]
Running action 1
Running action 3
Left "Oops on 3"
```

(But note that the computation here stops at the first error and doesn't soldier on until the bitter end -- which might not be what you had wanted. The `errors` package is certainly wide-ranging enough that many other variations are possible.)

Comment: Hm, I don't like this approach since i don't know how to deal with returned error message. I'm new to haskell but i suppose that instead of returning it's better to put it to the  logger monad.